# Browser plugin to prevent HTML5 videos from autoplaying

Tags: video, html, web-browser

A lot of news sites these days have the video automatically play when you go to the page. It used to be fine cause I had Flash only enabled when I click on, but with HTML5, it plays automatically.

Is there a plugin that allows me to disable this behaviour for HTML5 videos?

Comment: Do you care which browser, or are you wiling to switch to one with such a plugin?

Comment: Also, which Operating System should it run on?

Answer (score 3):

In **Firefox**, you can set `media.autoplay.enabled` to `false` (in [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config)).

This does work for many, but [not for all cases](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=659285) (i.e., where certain JavaScript gets used).

In addition or as alternative, you could use the popular Firefox add-on [**NoScript**](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/noscript/), which comes with a setting that enables click-to-play for HTML5’s `audio` and `video`.